# Send Data to Arduino

Tags: python-3.x, arduino

I try to Send Command Arduino Start drive
and ill get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moveMotors.py", line 289, in <module>
    main()
  File "moveMotors.py", line 285, in main
    followTheLine()
  File "moveMotors.py", line 250, in followTheLine
    moveMotors(maxMotorPWM, maxMotorPWM - pid)
  File "moveMotors.py", line 80, in moveMotors
    serialArduino.write(struct.pack('>B', right))
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

I Use Python3
this code on Python.

```
def moveMotors(left, right):
    '''Moves the motors with specific speed'''

    if (0 < left <= 255) or (0 < right <= 255):
        serialArduino.write(struct.pack('>B', 254)) # code 254 for moveStright() function on Arduino
        serialArduino.write(struct.pack('>B', left))
        serialArduino.write(struct.pack('>B', right))
    elif left == 0 and right == 0:
        serialArduino.write(struct.pack('>B', 253)) # code 253 for stop() function on Arduino
    else:
        print ("Speed must be an integer between 0 and 255.\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The traceback is giving you the vital clue. The `right` variable is not an integer. Check how you are calling the `moveMotors()` function and verify that `left` and `right` are always integers.

Comment: I need to search on Arduino Code or Python ?

Comment: Here file witch this Code:
https://github.com/nikgens/TankRobotProject/blob/master/moveMotors/moveMotors.py

Comment: As stated by @DavidCollins `left` and `right` are supposed to be integers. The code is fine and passes proper values to function maybe you are tweaking some variables, are you using the exact code?

Comment: Yes i use cloned code frome github.